# How can I add a value stored in a variable to a list?

Tags: lisp

For example:

```
(setf s 2)
    s => 2

(setf list1 '(1 s 3 4))
    list1 => (1 s 3 4)
```

How do i get it to add the value stored in s to the list?
For this example I would want to use s to generate a list (1 2 3 4)
I have a lisp book I'm reading and I can't seem to find any mention of how to do this so I thought i'd ask.
Thanks

Comment: '(1 ,s 3 4) should work (note the comma in front of s).

Comment: I just tried that and I get the following error (comma is illegal outside of backquote)

Comment: Yes, you should use a backquote (`), not a quote (').

Comment: Thanks! Silly of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So quoted data in Scheme are like String constants.. If I wrote `"1 s 3 4"` in Java I wouldn't be able to get `s` replaced with the variable contents. I 'd have to write `"1 " + s + " 3 4"`. In Lisp we have [backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) to do this in list structures:

```
`(1 ,s 3 4)
; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```

Note that this is a trick.. It's like "1 $s 3 4" in PHP as it's representing code that creates the list with the unquoted variables evaluated and return a new list structure. Under the hood it's very similar to writing:

```
(list 1 s 3 4)
; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```

And of course `list` is not a primitive since it just uses `cons`. What it does is this:

```
(cons 1 (cons s (cons 3 (cons 4 '()))))
; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Works great now!

Answer (score 1):

> I would want to use s to generate a list (1 2 3 4)

The function `list` can be handy:

```
CL-USER 14 > (let ((s '2))
               (list 1 s 3 4))
(1 2 3 4)
```

The function `LIST` creates a fresh new list from its arguments.